# Software For Concentration Inequalities

Tags: probability, reference-request, math-software

I am interested in experimenting and using symbolic algebra for work on concentration inequalities. Namely, I want to experiment with what kind of bounds are plausible for specifically chosen distributions. Example of the type of concentration inequalities that I want to experiment with are McDiarmid and Chernoff-type inequalities.

Is there any package on either R or SageMath (chosen because they are free) for these tasks, and is there any tutorial on how to use these software to experiment with concentration inequalities?

Comment: what you mean by experimenting with concentration inequalities?